# Where are we supposed to look for C++ constants? (that appear in MSDN documentation)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, shell

Please excuse the beginner's question. But searching hasn't uncovered anything, and my C# background doesn't help much.

MSDN regularly refers to constants without giving their numeric value. For example, [the documentation for SHChangeNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) refers to `SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED` . Where am I supposed to find these values? So I've found this particular one by searching the web. But a) I have to take someone's word for it without official documentation. b) where do I find these values in the future? What does a C++ developer, who has to use these values all the time, do?

Comment: C++ developers just use `SCHNE_ASSOCCHANGED` in the code and don't care what its value is.

Comment: @chris And where does that come from? Don't they have to `#include` some header library for that?

Comment: Yes, and that header is listed at the bottom of your link.

Comment: @chris Thanks. You can transform your comment into an answer (Though someone already posted it). You were actually the first to give me the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very link you posted has the answer:

> **Header**  `Shlobj.h`

You'll find the constants in the header file. The headers are distributed with the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I didn't notice that. (Can't accept yet.)

Comment: MSDN seems to be quite thorough nowadays, but just in case you ever encounter a case in which this line is absent: the default header for Windows constants, functions, and structures is `<windows.h>`. Because this is such a big header, you might want to pre-compile it.